# Giveaway Bot with Requirements (Message Counter, Role, Voice Chat time counter)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new to programming and I want to pursue being a software engineer. I'm developing my skills here at JavaScript.

So yeah, my question is: How do you make a giveaway bot that needs requirements? like Santa Wumpus premium, it has the option to have requirements like

1. you need to send 50 messages before you can enter the giveaway
2. you need to join vc and stay for 1 hour
3. you need to have the specific role to join the giveaway

something like that, thank you for helping.

And yeah, I've already completed the basic giveaway command. I only need the requirements thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so using discord.js you'd need to be tracking user activity somehow. Probably create a database that tracks message counts, vc time and then check the role later.

So for the messages, you'll want to capture the message event emitted by the client. Something like:

```
client.on('message', (message)=>{
    db.users.get(message.user.id).messages += 1
}
```

Then for the vc time, you'd need to do a bit more work, check the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) for the voice status update event. You'll be able to track when people join/leave vc, and then calculate how long they were in there with that, and add it to the database as well.

Then just run a function each time you update the database to check if they meet all criteria and if so check for the role and then add them to the giveaway. That should work or something along those lines.

If you need help getting started with dicord.js, check out https://discordjs.guide/
If you need specifics, read the documentation https://discord.js.org/#/docs

Comment: so if I use the database, it only counts the messages sent when the giveaway was created? or it counts all of their messages?

Comment: Well, the database is just a means to an end. Think of it as a really efficient array. It just holds data, creating/using the data is the interesting bit. That said, you'd be able to count from when it was created by doing something like creating a record per giveaway (per user) and then that way it'll only be incremented from message events after it was created. At any rate, incrementing from events will only add messages that were sent while it is counting them, so it's just a question of how you count them.